# Unable to Observe Failure/Pause States for Firebase Task iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage, background-process

I have a `FIRStorageUploadTask` that uploads an image to storage. I can successfully `observeStatus(.Progress)`, read and print the progress. And I can successfully observe the `.Success` status and notify the user of the upload being complete. However, when I disable WiFi/cellular data/turn on airplane mode during the upload, I simply stop receiving progress events. No notification of failure or pausing of the upload. The upload eventually continues once internet connection is reestablished. Can someone let me know how I can handle the `.Failure` and `.Pause` sates?

```
    //currentTask is a FIRStorageUploadTask object
    currentTask.observeStatus(.Progress) { (snapshot) in
        if let fraction = snapshot.progress?.fractionCompleted {
            //UI update method
            self.observeUploadProgress(fraction)
        }
    }
    currentTask.observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
        //UI update method
        self.observeUploadComplete()
    }
    currentTask.observeStatus(.Failure) { (snapshot) in
        //Never gets called, even when airplane mode is on during upload
        print("Failure status")
    }
    currentTask.observeStatus(.Pause) { (snapshot) in
        //Never gets called, even when airplane mode is on during upload
        print("Pause status")
    }
```

Comment: Hey Connor! Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Connor any update on this?

Comment: @T.Meyer nope. Just never implemented it. The Firebase API has changed a lot since this question, so I'm not sure whether the problem still exists.